# If multitenancy is a priority, should I store site content in the database?

Tags: asp.net, mvc, cms, multitenancy

I have a multi tenant ASP.NET MVC website and all client specific text is stored in resource files.  Every time someone wants to change text I have to jump through hoops and fill out forms and let someone else put it in production.  This was fine with 2 clients, but now we have 6 and are looking to roll out to 40+.  **I can't spend all day making text changes!**

Does anyone have any advice on how to make life eaiser?  I was thinking a CMS may not work because as far as i know most CMS's idea of multitenancy is to add an additional independent site.  We frequently roll out new features and I fear I'll be in the same boat adding modules and updating 40+ sites.  I prefer one site with different text if I can.

Any help is most appreciated!

Comment: [Creating a Data Driven ASP.NET Localization Resource Provider and Editor](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwdbresourceprovider/)

Comment: There are CMS's that support multi-tenancy. It's also sometimes called multi-site management. Here is a related StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267490/are-there-any-decent-open-source-multi-tenant-cmss-out-there

Comment: It doesn't have to be a database - it needs to be a shared store, be it a relational database, NoSQL or XML file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you certainly should store all client modifiable content into the database (or accessed via the database) so that the clients can maintain this for themselves.

You will need to spend some time writing the admin functions but you will reap the rewards in the long run. You are right you cannot have the situation where all changes need to go through the developers. You will end up spending all your time updating the sites.

You can, and probably should, introduce the changes gradually. Each time someone wants to change something add it (and a few related things) to the admin pages. That way you'll only have admin for the things that people actually *want* to change and not for the rest.

A few years ago I worked for a company producing themed sites for local papers and when I started there were few admin pages for these sites and my team were in the same position as you. I gradually introduced admin pages and everybody was happy. The team was happy as they could concentrate on development, the clients were happy as they could get their site updated when *they* wanted, the management were happy as the clients were happy.

Comment: This sounds like the direction we are going.  That's a great tip about introducing the changes gradually, it's something I can take to management!